# Python requests.post response body says b'Wrong capacity Value and wrong headers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to parse my Post response body:
When I do curl my service returns this response:

```
curl  -v -POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://localhost:6543/myservice -d '{"problem": {"capacity": 60, "weights": [10, 20, 33], "values": [10, 3, 30]}'

* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6543 (#0)
> POST /myservice HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6543
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 76
> 
* upload completely sent off: 76 out of 76 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 279
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
{
"problem" : {
    "capacity" : 60,
    "values" : [
        10,
        3,
        30
    ],
    "weights" : [
        10,
        20,
        33
    ]
},
"solution" : "{}",
"status" : "submitted",
"task" : "1001",
"timestamps" : {
    "completed" : "null",
    "started" : "null",
    "submitted" : "1552052954"
}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
}
```

When I to parse the response from python code:

```
post_url = "http://localhost:6543/myservice"
data = {"problem": {"capacity": 60, "weights": [10, 20, 33], "values": [10, 3, 30]}}

data_json = json.dumps(data)
res = requests.post(post_url, json={"text": data_json}, headers=    {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print(res.text)
print(res.headers)

Output:
{'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '20'}
Wrong capacity Value
```

What is wrong between two? Why my python response is not printing the body?
Also surprisingly output of headers is wrong too:
{'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '20'}

Answer (score 0):

You can send the dictionary itself (in other words, the API allows you to write code in such a way that it looks like you're sending the very `dict` object):

```
res = requests.post(post_url,
    json=data, # not `data_json`
    ...)
```